# Does Parse retry dropped requests?

Tags: parse-platform

Since parse has a limit of requests per second I was wondering if dropped requests are retried. Now I know requests that return with an error are retried automatically up to a certain number of attempts. Dropped requests come back with error 155 but I do not know if they are automatic retried just as other failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding , request that are dropped with the error 155 due to hitting the burst limit are not retried as they will fail again until the number of requests come down. You can implement some exception handling to retry these requests later.

Comment: More info here https://www.parse.com/questions/seeking-more-details-on-the-new-pricing-model